# Quitar fondo blanco ProgressDialog personalizado android studio

Tags: android-studio

estoy personalizando un progressDialog en android studio. Pero al ejecutar se muestra un fondo blanco como muestra la imagen
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Use lo siguiente para modificar el ProgressDialog:

```
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    progressDialog.show();
    progressDialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_progressdialog);
    progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
```

donde custom_progressdialog es el siguiente layout:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Cargando"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@color/progress_text"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"/>
```

Que a su vez hace uso del siguiente recurso drawable

```
<solid android:color="@color/progress_bg" />

<corners android:radius="10dp" />

<padding android:left="15dp" android:top="15dp" android:right="15dp" android:bottom="15dp"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Agrega esto:

```
progressDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

Eso te quitará el color del background que es blanco y solo te dejará lo que hayas cusrtomizado.

O bien también lo puedes hacer directamente en el *xml*:

Agregar esto a las propiedades de tu layout:

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

Comment: !ambas deben funcionar, usan el color transparente definido en el SDK. +1

Comment: Muchas gracias me sirvió el consejo =)